# I get an exception, "Element is no longer attached to DOM" when I run my code, but In Debug mode, it works fine. I'm using Java and TestNG

Tags: webdriver, java, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

In the webpage I'm testing, there are 3 options in a drop down and on selecting each option, rows in a table gets populated. I'm just trying to locate the table value through xpath and I am getting an the exception. Sharing the code I tried and the page source snippets. Please, help me out!!

```
   System.out.println("\n Unbranded Sample Packs tests: ");
      Reporter.log("   Unbranded sample packs validation   |");

      WebElement sp=driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/a/button"));

      if(sp.isDisplayed())
      {
          sp.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
          Thread.sleep(3000);
          String spurl=driver.getCurrentUrl();
          if(spurl.contains("unbranded-sample-packs"))
          {

              //Business card sample kit:

                WebElement w1=driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/button"));
                w1.click();
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/ul/li[1]/a/span")).click();

                WebElement p=driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div/a"));

                if(p.isDisplayed())
                {

                    if(p.getText().equals("£8.00"))
                    {
                        System.out.println("\n Business card sample kit displays the correct page");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.err.println("\n Business card sample kit option displays the wrong page !");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    System.err.println("\n Prices are not displayed");
                }

            // Reseller Catalogues:

                WebElement selectorElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/button"));
                try 
                {
                    WebElement sE=driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/button/span[2]"));
                    sE.click();
                } 

                catch (NoSuchElementException e) 
                { 
                    selectorElement.click();
                    WebElement sE=driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/button/span[2]"));
                    sE.click();

                }

                try 
                {
                    WebElement elementOfInterest = selectorElement.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/ul/li[2]/a/span"));
                    elementOfInterest.click();
                    System.out.println("\n Reseller catalogues option is clicked");
                } 

                catch (NoSuchElementException e) 
                { 
                    selectorElement.click();
                    WebElement elementOfInterest = selectorElement.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/ul/li[2]/a/span"));
                    elementOfInterest.click();
                    System.out.println("\n Reseller catalogues option is clicked");
                }

            //  Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/ul/li[2]/a/span"))); dropdown.selectByVisibleText("Reseller Catalogues");

    /*      
         * 
         * JavascriptExecutor executor= (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
                executor.executeScript("document.getElementById('ID').style.display='block';");
                Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("ID")));
                select.selectByVisibleText("value");
                Thread.sleep(6000);    

        */
                new WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div/a")));




                if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div/a")).isDisplayed())
                {
                    new WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div/a")));

                    if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div/a")).getText().equals("£10.00"))
                    {
                        System.out.println("\n Reseller Catalogues displays the correct page");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.err.println("\n Reseller Catalogues displays the wrong page !");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    System.err.println("\n Prices are not displayed");
                }

            //Unbranded sample pack option is selected


                WebElement selectorElement1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/button"));
                try 
                {
                    WebElement sE=driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/button/span[2]"));
                    sE.click();
                } 

                catch (NoSuchElementException e) 
                { 
                    selectorElement1.click();
                    WebElement sE=driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/button/span[2]"));
                    sE.click();

                }


                try 
                {
                    WebElement elementOfInterest = selectorElement1.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/ul/li[3]/a/span"));
                    elementOfInterest.click();
                    System.out.println("\n Unbranded Sample pack option is clicked");
                } 

                catch (NoSuchElementException e) 
                { 
                    selectorElement1.click();
                    WebElement elementOfInterest = selectorElement1.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/ul/li[3]/a/span"));
                    elementOfInterest.click();
                    System.out.println("\n Unbranded Sample pack option is clicked");
                }

                new WebDriverWait(driver, 6).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div/a")));
                WebElement p3=driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div/a"));


                if(p3.isDisplayed())
                {

                    new WebDriverWait(driver, 6).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div/a")));
                    WebElement p4=driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div/a"));

                    if(p4.getText().equals("£12.00"))
                    {
                        System.out.println("\n Unbranded Sample Pack displays the correct page");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.err.println("\n Unbranded sample pack displays the wrong page !");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    System.err.println("\n Prices are not displayed");
                }

                System.out.println("\n 'Finished size' dropdowns validated \n");
                Reporter.log("   'Finished size' dropdowns Validation done   |");
          }
          else
          {
              System.err.println("\n Sample Pack button links to a wrong path");
          }

      }
      else
      {
          System.err.println("\n Sample packs button is not available");
      }

      System.out.println("\n Unbranded Sample packs validated \n");
      Reporter.log("   Sample packs Validation done   |");
```

}

Page Source:

[image: Page source for Dropdown options]
[image: Page source for table]

Comment: Please provide error trace and also line number which you have got error.

Comment: at what step are you hitting with the exception. Merely providing the code won't help much.

Comment: I'm using firefox browser.. Even if I add wait statements before locating the elements I get the same error.. Tried out with WebDriverWait, Thread.sleep.. both didn't work..

Comment: Out of those three dropdowns, first option is working.. The second and third are not working and it stops in on Selection of the second dropdown..(Reseller Catalogues).. Not sure about the line number.. Please help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are getting this error because : You are immediately (before the page load could finish) searching for an element and finding it.

> there are 3 options in a dropdown and on selecting each option, rows
>   in a table gets populated.

When dealing with asynchronous pages use proper waits after every anticipated page-load.

Insert an explicit wait after the selecting element from drop down and wait for the new content to load. Search for the element you want only after the wait statements. This will also increase the robustness of your tests significantly.

Comment: Improve your answer by referencing a resource to help them implement it eg
http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp

Answer (score 0):

If you are using chrome browser it might help if you update the chromedriver.exe to the latest version.

The "stale element" and "no such element" errors was fixed in ChromeDriver 2.19

https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

Which browser does this code run on? FF? Chrome?

Comment: Shouldn't this be a comment ?

Comment: I don't have 50 reputation to add it as a comment

Comment: I tried to leave a comment below the author's post but it said that i don't have score of 50 reputation

Comment: Answer edited with more information